# Pretraining for BERT using Google Cloud Platform TPU v3

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bert-language-model, tpu, google-cloud-shell

We are trying to pre-train BERT using the corpus we have prepared.

I tried to pre-train BERT with TPU v3 using Cloud Shell with the help of this tutorial(https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/tutorials/bert), but Cloud Shell has a usage limit of 60 hours per week, which does not allow us to efficiently perform very time-consuming calculations like BERT pre-training.

If we want to do non-stop pre-training for BERT using TPU v3 on Google Cloud Platform, how is the best way to do it?

It would be very helpful if you could provide a specific process if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can run long running programs using one of [nohup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup), [tmux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux) or [screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen).

You ssh to your Compute VM (using Cloud Shell) by running

`gcloud compute ssh my-vm-name --zone=us-central1-b`

Then run your pertaining command (say using nohup)

`nohup training_command.py > mytraining.out 2> mytraining.err`

Your training will continue to run even if Cloud Shell expires or you close the window.
You can reconnect back to the VM and see the outputs of training in those files.